# Workflow Manager - Authentication Issue

Tags: workflow, 2013

I've been trying to install Workflow Manager to work on my SP2013 farm but getting some odd errors that I'm unable to diagnose.

When browsing to the https://workflow.domain:12290 via an elevated IE browser - I'm constantly asked to provide authentication.

Also when running a `Get-WFFarmStatus` I get the error on WorkFlowServiceFrontEnd claiming it could not establish a trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Unless I'm missing stuff from the guides I've seen I'm not sure what I need to do to enable this and allow workflow to start connecting!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the errors? Hard to help without seeing them :)

Also, it is expected you are bring prompted to login when hitting the WF endpoint. Could this be [related to your other question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79275/sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-missing-service/81292#81292)?