# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow Manager Missing Service

Tags: 2013, workflow

Got a weird issue with one of my SP2013 farms and was hoping for some guidance.

Whenever I issue the register-spworkflowservice command it only creates the SP Workflow service proxy and not the actual service.

Central Admin looks like this [image: central admin]

The service proxy shows that workflow manager is connecting but whenever I try to publish a workflow via SPDesigner it will throw errors saying it can't communicate with the workflow service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally see that error in my development environment after coming back from a saved state. Usually rebooting the servers in the farm resolves it. Sometimes I also see the networking get screwy so an IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS can resolve this.

Do you have WM on the same box as SP?

Try to re-establish the connection by running the PowerShell pairing command again, this time with a -force argument. You should see both the service app & proxy in CA. If not, check the ULS logs when you run the pairing command.

Comment: Turns out the issue seems to be as you say with networking going screwy between the servers.

WM was on a seperate box not running SP. Tried multiple times to remove the service application but it seemed to keep some trace of it. Doing the above ipconfig/flushdns and a full service stop and reboot finally allowed me to remove the service completely.

Running the powershell again created the full service app/proxy.