# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Service Application not visible in Central Admin nor in Get-SPServiceApplication

Tags: 2013, workflow, central-administration

I found this posting

[Sharepoint 2013 Workflow Manager Missing Service](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79275/sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-missing-service)

when looking for an answer to the very same symptom -- and when I saw Andrew Connell answering figured I was saved!

But, no such luck.

No matter what I do, I can only get the "Workflow Service Application Proxy" to appear.  Now, I wouldn't care so much -- except that I also can't get workflows to work on one of my farms.  As far as I can see, I've set it up identically to others which DO work -- and interestingly one of my other farms where WorkFlow works has that same symptom!

What I mean by not working is that a workflow will work if it's just working on one list item -- for instance, it can set field values.  However, if it tries to look up from another list in the same site, it ultimately dies -- first it has six goes at retrying the lookup, with the error "HTTP NotFound to http://xxx.com/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')/Items(4)?%24select=ID% ... etc, and then it gets suspended with "Details: An Unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance.  Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 {"error":{"code":"-2130575322, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"List does not exist.\u000a\u000aThe page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."}}}...

Other points that may have bearing :
1. these farms were set up with AutoSPInstaller -- but of course the WorkFlow was added on in retrospect -- everything else (other than the non-appearing service) seems to work

2. WF/SB is running on a separate server
3. I have tried configuring with WF/SB directly on the SP server with no luck
4. I have another SP farm that works on the same network, I can pair that SP farm with the WF/SB server from this farm and it still works, but if I pair this SP farm with the WF/SB server from the other farm, nothing changes.  Ergo, I think the problem is with this farm
5. The farm config is a single SP server with all SP roles (just SP, no AD / DC / etc), connecting to a single WF/SB server - there is also a single SQL server with 3 instances (one for SP, one for WF, one for SB).

UPS works fine, mysites works fine, get-spserviceapplication does NOT show Workflow Service Application in the list, and neither does that show up on the server which works.

I've watched the ULS, I've checked the dbo.DebugTraces table in the WFInstanceManagementDB, I've looked in the WF Management logs and the IIS logs ... there is a top-level root site, I've made sure the SB & WF CU1's are in place ... I'm exhausted!

Thankfully these are VM's -- how did we ever survive without snapshots?

Comment: I know it's an old question, but do you see it if you run PowerShell `Get-SPServiceApplication | select TypeName`?

Answer (score 0):

How about an entry in that server's Hosts file?  When the WF does a lookup, it's calling a URL.  That `xxx.com` you mentioned could probably use entering in that server's Hosts file that has the workflow "failing".  If this is a single-server farm, just mark it with `127.0.0.1`.  It could be trying to go to http:\\servername instead of http:\\server.mydomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, your workflow service is not connected.

For troubleshooting this issue, I recommend to verify the things below:

1. Check the workflow management site is starting. If yes, restart the workflow management site.
2. Check the ULS log to see some information about your problem.
3. Re-register workflow service with force: `Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite “yoursitecollectionaddress” -WorkflowHostUri "http://workflow.example.com:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp -force`
4. Run the PowerShell command to see if the issue still occurs: `Enable-SPFeature -Identity WorkflowServiceStore –Url $yourUrl`

Per my knowledge, you do not need to start user profile synchronization service when configuring the workflow manager.

However, the user who deploys and runs a workflow must be added to the User Profile service, so it is recommended to start the user profile service application.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588(v=office.15).aspx

More reference:

- http://www.datazx.cn/Forums/en-US/7675ea81-457d-4491-a224-e34471beec63/action?threadDisplayName=sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-not-connected&forum=sharepointcustomization
- [Sharepoint 2013 Workflow Manager Missing Service](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79275/sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-missing-service)
- http://anujabhojani.blogspot.be/2013/06/the-option-for-sharepoint-2013-workflow.html